# Template data structure - Access to getters and setters of a template class deriving from an abstract class

Tags: c++, database, templates, abstract

in a finite element code, I’ve a data structure to manipulate the value of a field (coordinates, temperature, ...) at a point. This structure is basic and looks like this:

```
class point_data
{
public:
    void allocate(int ldim); // allocation of data;
    const double* get_data() const { return data; }
    void set_data(const double* ldata); // for example
    …
protected:
    double* data;
    …
}
```

I then use objects of type `point_data*` to evaluate expressions, for example to impose boundary conditions. To be concrete, if x, y are the coordinate fields, and I impose a temperature T equal to sin(y) on a boundary defined by x == 0, then I have a “sin” operator object, whose evaluate method takes a `point_data*` argument (in fact a `point_data**`) and return a `point_data*` containing the result. Same thing for my “==” object, which also takes a `point_data**` argument (array of two `point_data*` this time) and return the result.

As my structure for supporting data of global fields is already template, and since it is this structure that creates `point_data` objects, I wanted templatized the class `point_data`. Then, I tried:

```
class abstract_point_data
 {
 protected:     
     int dim;     
 public:
     abstract_point_data() : dim{0} { ; }
     virtual ~abstract_point_data() { ; }
     
     const int& get_dim() const { return dim; }
     void set_dim(int ldim) { dim = ldim; }
     
     virtual void allocate(int ldim=0) = 0;
     // get_data ??? set_data ???
 };
 
 template <typename T>
 class point_data : public abstract_point_data
 {
 public:
     point_data() : my_data{0}, allocated{false} { ; }
     virtual ~point_data() { delete_data(); }
     
     virtual void set_data(const T* ldata);
     virtual const T* get_data() const { return my_data; }

     virtual void allocate(int ldim);
     
 protected:
     
     T* my_data;
     bool allocated;
     
    void delete_data() { if ( allocated ) { delete [] my_data; allocated = false; } }
 };
 
template <typename T> 
 void point_data<T>::allocate(int ldim)
{
    dim = ldim;
    delete_data();
    my_data = new T[ldim];
    allocated = true;
}


template <typename T>
void point_data<T>::set_data(const T* ldata)
{
    for (int i=0; i<dim; i++)
        my_data[i] = ldata[i];
}
```

with the main:

```
    abstract_point_data* mp = new point_data<double>;
    mp->allocate(1);
    double val = 1.0;
   ( (point_data<double>*) mp)->set_data(&val);    
    
    delete mp;
```

This way, the evaluate method of my operator objects can have an `abstract_point_data**` as an argument. In can also create the result object, because I know for example that a sine provide a double, or by cloning one of the arguments. But, that’s it. In general, I don’t know the type of my arguments in the evaluate function and therefore I can’t (of course) access the getters and setters. I’ve tried things like CRTP, `decltype(auto)`, or even stupid stuff like `std::tuple<bool,int,double> my_types;` + `decltype(std::get<get_my_index()>(my_types))` to store the type of my template “in” abstract_point_data, but nope, the C++ rules seem inviolable.

Can anyone give me an idea or reference to help me redefine (if possible) an acceptable templatized data structure? Thanks in advance.

In addition : the reason of using abstract_point_data was (if it worked) to only deal with abstract_point_data objects (as method arguments, in containers...), instead of dealing with `point_data<int>`, `point_data<double`>, ... (but maybe I missed something).

Comment: any reason you're using `abstract_point_data` (instead of template)? and please also provide relevant code that use it. (your class doesn't have `virtual` function so it'd not work anyway.)

Comment: Who's got ownership of the data in`double* data;`? If it's `point_data` you could make it  `std::vector<T> data;` or `std::unique_ptr<T> data;` instead.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what you want to achieve. The abstract base pattern you currently have is indeed useful if you want to have something like a `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<abstract_point_data>>`. Echoing Ted Lyngmo's comment, you can avoid the potential headaches of memory management and let a container or smart pointer do it for you. The smart pointers support polymorphism, so you could use the above vector to store a `std::unique_ptr<point_data<double>>`.

To get your functions/objects to work with the derived types, you can make them templates as well, for example:

```
template<typename T, typename U>
bool operator==(point_data<T> const& x, point_data<U> const& y) 
{ return x.get_data() == y.get_data(); }
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this advice. I had thought of using template classes for my "operators", but I wanted to try to avoid that as it is a lot of work (in fact, each of my operators is a derived class and not an operator in the C++ sense, and such an operator object is created at runtime by an object factory technique, but anyway). However, if that's the way to do it, I'll do it, and I'll use smart pointers.

Comment: @JulienB. I guessed as much. My example is what I would write for a nonpolymorphic case, but while it's easy to write this kind of generic code, actually calling it using polymorphic references is less trivial. For example, virtual functions can't be templates. You'll have to consider whether you really want the mixed static and dynamic polymorphism. An alternative could be to contain the type variation in union-like types, such as `std::variant` and `std::any`.